# Не вызывается функция jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: форма + код]

Имеется форма с обыкновенным полем `input-text`, ниже список введенных данных, который берется из БД.

1) Есть функция `$("#FormSubmit").click(function () {..}` , которая добавляет в список только что введенное имя, через `append`. Далее это имя передает через ajax и добавляется в БД.

2) Есть функция `$(".cat_del").click(function() {..}` , которая при нажатии на крестик(удаление) скрывает нужную строку из списка через `hide()`, далее ajax посылает команду на удаление из БД нужной записи. Всё работает, если загрузить страницу и начать удалять, а вот если добавить новую запись и уже на ней кликнуть на `.cat_del`(удалить), то функция не вызывается, а работать начинает, если перезагрузить страницу.

Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что у вас были записи, которым вы назначили (типа, эй вы, все кто с классом cat_del) функцию на удаление. А потом вы добавили еще одну запись, но ведь ей вы на удаление ничего не назначали (она ведь новенькая и той вашей команды не слышала).

Как вариант решения, в ajax-е, в `success:function` заново написать `$(".cat_del").click(function() {..}`, а лучше все это вынести в отдельную функцию.

Или переписать вашу функцию примерно так:

`$('body').on('click', '.cat_del', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        ... дальше ваш код
}`

в этом случае все будет работать и без повторного вызова после ajax-a

Comment: Отлично, спасибо!